# how to get my concur to fly to me

Tags: training

I have just got a green cheek concur I been told he is bout 5 yrs old hand tame and talks but he is not I have got him to step on my finger in the cage by using treats  to get him to step on but that's it he seems happy he purrs when he  like something. I also have a rock pebbler and a ring neck they girls how do I get him to fly to me out of the cage

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track using treats to get him to step up. Keep doing that until he will do it reliably. Then start holding your hand a little farther away and coaxing him to climb or hop onto your hand. When he's hopping reliably, you can increase the distance so that he's got to fly a little to get to you. Over time, keep holding your hand farther and father away and eventually he'll be flying to you for treats.

Be very patient and work in small increments. Remember you must have a good relationship with your bird, if he doesn't trust you he won't care to come to you. If he seems to have trouble with a certain distance, move a little closer or offer a higher-value treat.